# React function component sharing state

Tags: reactjs

I am experiencing an error when sharing state in two React components. so currently the issue I am experiencing is cannot restructure property 'input' of 'undefined' as it is undefined. so I supposed the input state is not being shared from `RenderContent` component. I have tried useContext but I am sure how to construct it.

RenderContent.js

```
export const RenderContent = () => { 
  const [input, setInput] = useState(''); 
  return ( 
    <form>
     <input
      type="text"
      onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
      value={input}
      onBlur={() =>delay(() =>setInput(''),150}
      placeholder='placeholder here...'
     />
    </form>
  );
};
```

RenderAction.js

```
export const RenderContent =  (input) => {  
  return ( 
    //...some code goes here
  );
};
```

so can see the input state in the `RenderContent` component is stored in this function component, but I want to do a state lift somehow transfer the state into parent component, since they share the same parent so that I can pass input state into `renderAction` component. but I am not sure how should I manipulate this.

I have attached parent component as reference.

```
<Dialog
 renderContent={RenderContent}
 renderAction={RenderAction}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  return <Dialog
    renderContent={<RenderContent input={input} setInput={setInput} />}
    renderAction={<RenderAction input={input} setInput={setInput} />}
  />
}

export const RenderContent =  (props) => {  
const {input, setInput} = props;
  return ( 
    //...some code goes here
  );
};
```

Comment: but here RenderContent has to be function can be a component... that's actually can pass the props here:(